# I can't see delete button in iOS 8 in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have just programmed a UITableView with Objective C code. I am not able to see the delete button or delete the UITableviewCell.

***Code for ViewController.m***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * numbers;

@end
```

***Code for ViewController.m:***

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTableView, numbers;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Kid 1", @"Kid 2", nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;


}

-(void)insertNewObject{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[alert show];

}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return numbers.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate methods

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *tmpTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

        if (!numbers) {
            numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [numbers insertObject:tmpTextField atIndex:0];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

            [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }

    }

}

@end
```

Please Help.

Comment: Where are you putting the table into editing mode?

Comment: `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}`

Comment: You're missing `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method. Where you'll return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` plus how are you making tableview to go into edit mode? or are you swiping the row to reveal delete option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code block:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a way to put the table view into editing mode. So if you have an edit button you're going to put the following in the selector

```
 - (void)editPressed:(UIButton *)editButton
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

From there, you should be all set with the other code that you've got.